# Create a custom map for Android app

Tags: android

I want to create an android application for a shopping mall. I want to have a map (custom map) and when user selects certain store ( i.e. Lacoste ) then i want to add a pin on the location on the map where that store is located.

For this i don't need to use a gps,  but i need to add pins to my map when store/stores are selected.

My problem is that i don't know if that should be done with an image that i edit at runtime ( which sounds bit too complicated ) or maybe there is some simpler way to do so.

Any suggestions, tutorials, or anything helpful?

Thanks!

Comment: did You look this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/ ?

Comment: I have taken a look at it, but i didn't notice anything that would solve my problem.

Comment: Let me clarify one thing, are You going to use GoogleMap in your app? Now I see that You mentioned "custom map".

Comment: I just have an image that when clicked i need to put a pin to it. It doesn't require any geo location, gps or anything related to google maps.

Comment: Well, if You want to draw pin on image when the user click on map, you just have to draw it. Look here: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Comment: I know, i just asked is there a simpler way to do this, drawing constantly seems too complicated.

Comment: Well, in fact it's not. But it would be easier with Google Map API, and I would recommend You using it.